# SQL Update statement on Winforms

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, winforms

I'm still learning C#, I wanna ask about Update statement, I got a problem when updating data ... the process is success but data on database doesn't updated..  Did i do some mistake on this?

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=cproject;Uid=root;Pwd=admin");
MySqlDataAdapter oDA;
DataTable oDT = new DataTable();
MySqlCommand job;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     job = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE barang SET Nama_barang = '"+txtNama+"' AND Jumlah_barang='"+txtStock+"' AND Harga_awal='"+txtBeli+"' AND Harga_jual='"+txtJual+"' WHERE ID = '"+txtIndex+"'", con);
     try
     {
        con.Open();
        job.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("sukses");
        con.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

did I do something wrong?

Comment: Syntax errors in your UPDATE statement and you have to care about Injection as well

Comment: Are all your fields VARCHAR? I doubt so. use `Using` and `Parameterized Queries`

Comment: @un-lucky : i already tried with parameters but still can't too :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few Instructions: You are trying the wrong syntax here for `SQL UPDATE`, IF you have to update more columns then each one should be separated with commas, not with `AND`, One more thing you have to take care of is that your code opens a wide door for hackers through [injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), To close this door you have to use parameterized queries. Another thing( but not sure), The names `txtNama`, `txtStock` etc looks like the names of TextBoxes if so you have to use its `.Text`  properties as well. if not use proper naming conventions.

In simple your code should be like the following:

```
MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE barang SET Nama_barang =@Nama_barang,Jumlah_barang=@Jumlah_barang,Harga_awal=@Harga_awal,Harga_jual=@Harga_jual WHERE ID =@id", con);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nama_barang", txtNama.Text);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Jumlah_barang", txtStock.Text);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Harga_awal", txtBeli.Text);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Harga_jual", txtJual.Text);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtIndex.Text);
try
{
   con.Open();
   sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   MessageBox.Show("sukses");
   con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

You can try `.Parameters.Add()` if the values are of different types,

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the values coming in from TextBox as the Naming shows `txtNama`, `txtStock` So it should be `txtNama.Text`, `txtStock.Text` respectively. Another one which I believe it should be is that the Table in the DB would not be all Varchar Field. For Varchar field we need `'Value'` but for int or numbers we should not be using `'value'` whereas it should be `value`. So your Query should look like

```
"UPDATE barang SET Nama_barang = '" + txtNama.Text + "', Jumlah_barang=" + txtStock.Text + ", Harga_awal=" + txtBeli.Text + ", Harga_jual='" + txtJual.Text + "' WHERE ID = " + txtIndex.Text
```

I am not sure which of the fields are numeric. So I just removed `''` for few which I think would be numeric. Now you should use `Using` Statement and `Parameterized Query` to care the SQL Injection. and thus your code would look like

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        { 
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE barang SET Nama_barang = @namabarang, Jumlah_barang = @Jumlahbarang, Harga_awal= @Hargaawal, Harga_jual=@Hargajual WHERE ID = @myID";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@namabarang", txtNama.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Jumlahbarang", txtStock.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hargaawal", txtNama.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hargajual", txtBeli.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myID", txtJual.Text);
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        } 
}
```

Comment: Which means Syntax for SQL Update is different for Plain text queries and parameterized queries, right? you have `AND` as column separator in plain text query and `,` in parameterized

Comment: Nope I did it sequentially to make it right. But Lemme correct that too. Since I didnt write about it.

Comment: Better you remove that concatenated string, since it doesn't make sense as you are suggesting Parameterized